# how to use an inner abstract class without using its parent class name in another class in android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, inner-classes

```
public final class FeedReaderContract {
   // To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class,
   // give it an empty constructor.
   public FeedReaderContract() {}

   /* Inner class that defines the table contents */
   public static abstract class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
       public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entry";
       public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID = "entryid";
       public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
       public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE = "subtitle";
       ...
   }
}
```

when i do

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
"CREATE TABLE " + FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
FeedEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
... // Any other options for the CREATE command
" )";
```

I am not able to use `FeedEntry` directly. I have to use `FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME` instead of `FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME`.
How to use `FeedEntry` directly??

Comment: It is basically a java question and not a question directly related to android. So it will be better if you can add the java tag.

Comment: ok done now can you help me with the answer?

Comment: `import static FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry;`

Comment: yeah thanks it worked

Comment: Btw, your comment `To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class, give it an empty constructor.` does not seem to make sense. You probably want a `private` constructor here.